# How to add new sorting option for product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.1.0

By default Magento provide **Position** , **Name** and **Price** sorting option for products.

But I want to add new sorting option **Price high to low** , **Price low to high** and **Latest arrivals**.

So how can I add my custom sorting options?

I want to know how can we add any custom sorting option so in future if I want to add any option I can do myself.I want to know code flow for sorting functionality and what steps are required to fulfill this functionality?

I have googled and find [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124656/how-to-change-sort-by-option-in-filter-magento-2) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option) but none of are useful.