# What is the replacement of getOrderUrl() in Toolbar.php?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1.x versions we have the function called `getOrderUrl()` in **Toolbar.php** whereas in Magento 2, I couldn't found the same function.

My question here is, How can I get the same function? So that I can add few more sort options in toolbar area.

In Magento 1.x versions,
`<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected=”selected”<?php endif; ?>>Price : Low To High</option>`. Here getOrderUrl will be generated in **value attribute**.

I want to generate the `getOrderUrl` in Magento 2.

It would be appreciated someone provide solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getOrderUrl()` was removed in Magento 2. In Magento 1, this function provided us a real order url. However, **in Magento 2, we use Javascript to process the order url**: **`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/list/toolbar.js`**

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have to make some changes according to the requirement.

Comment: TS Guhan Can you please tell me changes as I also need to price asc and desc in sorting

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else wants to change the default direction you can use a plugin like this:

Make a file di.xml inside Vendor/Catalog/etc/frontend

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin sortOrder="1" name="vendorCatalogToolbar"
            type="Vendor\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductList\ToolbarPlugin"/>
</type>
```

and then make the file ToolbarPlugin.php inside
Vendor/Catalog/Plugin/Block/Product/ProductList/ToolbarPlugin.php

The code here is :

namespace Vendor\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Product\ProductList;
class ToolbarPlugin
{

```
public function beforeSetDefaultDirection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, $dir)
{

    if($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'name'){
        $dir= 'asc';
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

}

I m doing it like this because the default direction for my site has been set to desc with the use of xml.